# JQuery UI - How to get rid of outline in Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Whenever I click on any tab in Jquery UI Tab Widget there is always a outline (border). Is there any possibility of removing it or its just a browser specific issue.
**Note**
I don't have any code handy as I'm not sure how to proceed.

**Here is the screenshot**. Notice the Blue border around the first tab.

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `outline:none;` in css would do for you.

Comment: Cool. Will try it out.

Comment: @Jai: In which css class I need to add this to? Any idea?

Comment: @Java_User Posted a Solution and demo so you can check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JS BIN DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/pum/1/)

Only Need to add this in css

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-anchor {outline:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in css:

```
#tabs a {
   outline: none;
}
```

---

You can add this css snippet in your css file which is defined in the head and appears last.

or you can update this in *jQuery-ui.css* @ **line number 757**

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active .ui-tabs-anchor,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled .ui-tabs-anchor,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading .ui-tabs-anchor {
    cursor: text;
    outline: none; // <---add this
}
```